# Find an algorithm to evaluate unknown polynomial of degree $n$ given its values for $x=0,x=1, x=2,\ldots,x=n$

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

Given $n+1$ values ($P(0),P(1), P(2),\ldots,P(n)$) of unknown polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $n$ find an algorithm that works in $O(n^2)$ for evaluating $P(n+1), P(n+2),\ldots,P(2n)$.

Given $n+1$ values you could find polynomial coefficients explicitly but it'll take $O(n^3)$.

Comment: You need to be given $n+1$ values in order to uniquely determine a polynomial of degree $n$.

Comment: @David forgot about P(0). thanks.

Comment: Try Lagrangian interpolation.

Answer (score 5):

You can use finite differences to find the other values: Just write these values in one line, the differences between consecutive values in the next line, the differences between consecutive differences in the next line, and so on for $n$ lines. The last line has only one value but it is actually constant. Now work your way up to find the values of $P$ at the other points.

Here is an example for $P(x)=x^3+1$:
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 2 & 9 & 28\\
1 & 7 & 19\\
6 & 12\\
6
\end{array}
\qquad\to\qquad 
\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 2 & 9 & 28 & 65 & 126 & 217\\
1 & 7 & 19 & 37 & 61 & 91\\
6 & 12 & 18 & 24 & 30\\
6 & 6 & 6 & 6
\end{array}
$$

The data on the left consists of $O(n^2)$ values computed top-down at cost $O(1)$ per entry. The new data on the right consists of $O(n^2)$ values computed bottom-up at cost $O(1)$ per entry. Hence the total cost is $O(n^2)$.

This technique also works for finding a polynomial of degree $n$ from its values at $n+1$ consecutive integers. See [Newton's series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton.27s_series). The polynomial will be expressed in the binomial basis, not the power basis, using the coefficients in the first column.

Comment: Or in a recursive formulation: extend the $n$ values $P(1)-P(0), P(2)-P(1), \ldots, P(n)-P(n-1)$ of a degree $n-1$ polynomial $\Delta P$ to find $P(n+1)-P(n), \ldots P(2n)-P(2n-1)$ then compute $P(n+1), \ldots, P(2n)$ by adding terms from left to right.

Comment: @WimC, right! (BTW, nice to you here!)

Comment: I do more math as a hobby these days than programming. Hope you don't mind.  ;-)